The Telegraf plugin inputs.docker is not executed in the interval
I have the problem that in Telegraf the plugin inputs.docker is not executed in the time interval. However, other plugins (e.g. inputs.file or inputs.socket_listener) work.
When I start Telegraf once (telegraf --once) the data is written without any problems.
Can you help me here?
Here is an excerpt from my Telegraf configuration.
[agent]
  interval = "10m"
  ...
[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
  # WORKS
  ...
[[inputs.file]]
  # WORKS
  ...
[[inputs.socket_listener]]
  # WORKS
  ...
[[inputs.docker]]
  # Works only with --once
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  gather_services = false
  container_names = []
  source_tag = false
  container_name_include = []
  container_name_exclude = []
  container_state_include = ["created", "restarting", "running", "removing", "paused", "exited", "dead"]
  container_state_exclude = []
  timeout = "5s"
  perdevice = true
  total = false
  docker_label_include = []
  docker_label_exclude = []

Telegraf runs in a Docker container. Here is an excerpt from my docker-compose.yml
telegraf:
  image: telegraf
  restart: "no"
  ports:
    - 12003:12003
    - 2003:2003
  depends_on:
    - influxdb2
  volumes:
    - /mnt/dockervolumes/telegraf/telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:ro
    - /mnt/dockervolumes/telegraf/data:/home/data:ro
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro


I've found the problem.
It seems to be a permission problem. I've had to add this user option to my docker-compose.yml
user: telegraf:<number_of_docker_group>

